# TAB autocomplete não funciona com o NPM

Tags: npm, terminal, osx

É bem simples, o autocomplete funciona sempre menos quando começa com npm.

Alguém sabe me explicar o que é isso e como arrumar?

Answer (score 0):

O *completion* do npm no seu shell não vem de fábrica. Para isso, o npm recomenda o [npm-completion](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/completion).

Ele já é nativo do npm, você só precisa chamá-lo na inicialização do seu shell. Adicione o seguinte no arquivo de configuração do seu shell (`~/.zshrc` se você usa zsh, ou `~/.bashrc`, se você usa bash):

```
source <(npm completion)
```

Comment: Agradeço! Adicionei isso no ~/.zshrc, mas não deu...

Está assim:
# Activating autocomplete after npm
source <(npm completion)